# Unwanted curve tilting with hooked vertices

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices, parent, hook-modifier

I have an extruded curve of which both vertices are hooked to an empty each.
I need those for animation purposes.

Both empties are parented to an object to follow along. While rotating the object the curve starts twisting and tilting even though the relative position of the hooks does not change. It seems like the vertices keep a global orientation although hooked to new objects.
Why does it do that? and is it possible to shut it off?

[image]

Comment: It should work fine, maybe there's a parentage problem like you've parented the hook parent to the curve? Maybe share your file?

Comment: I've tried very parent-type with no result. Edited my question with link to drive. you#ll find a file and video there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hooks (Empties.001 and Empties.002) control curve point's locations and rotations (Tilt), but Curve object (container storing curve data) itself isn't rotating (location and rotation is still the same) see Origin, so the *Extrude* parameter is still pointing to Z direction.

It means Tilling is OK, but Curve object needs some love ...

**Parent** *Curve* to *Empty*
(or add *Constraint* > **Copy Rotation** to your *Curve* object with *Target > Empty*)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!